# How to zoom all of the ImageView on a pinch zoomable FrameLayout when zooming the FrameLayout?

Tags: android, image-processing, matrix, multi-touch, pinchzoom

The ZoomLayout is a customized class which is extends FrameLayout and implemented pinch zoom function on it.
PS: Single tap will add one ImageView into the ZoomLayout

idea: zoom the frameLayout, every child zoom togeather.

Result: not working.

Any other method?

```
<ZoomLayout
   android:id="@+id/graphics_holder"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFloorPlan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix" />

</ZoomLayout>


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout {

    Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    private PointF curr;
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;

    static final int CLICK = 3;

    float saveScale = 1f;

    protected float origWidth, origHeight;

    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private View currentView;
    private ImageView imgFloorPlan;
    private ArrayList<MyImageView> imgPointArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        super.setClickable(true);
        Activity act = (Activity) getContext();

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(act, new ScaleListener());
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(act, new ZoomGesture());

        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        imgFloorPlan = (ImageView) act.findViewById(R.id.imgFloorPlan);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                currentView = v;
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);

                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                imgFloorPlan.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                for (ImageView imageView:imgPointArray) {
                    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;

            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;

            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {

        matrix.getValues(m);

        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {

        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;

        return 0;

    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.d("ZoomLayout", "onMeasure called");
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        // Rescales image on rotation
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;

        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {

            //Fit to screen.
            float scale;
            Activity act = (Activity) getContext();
            imgFloorPlan = (ImageView) act.findViewById(R.id.imgFloorPlan);
            Drawable drawable = imgFloorPlan.getDrawable();

            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;

            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;

            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

            imgFloorPlan.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            for (ImageView imageView:imgPointArray) {
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
        }

        fixTrans();
    }

    class ZoomGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener { //单手指操作

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO: Add on Touch event to place point
            int x = (int) e.getX();
            int y = (int) e.getY();
            Log.d("PlayAreaView", "onSingleTapConfirmed" + x + "," + y);

            int imageViewWH = (int) DimensionUtils.dpToPx(currentView, 60);

            if (isTapOnFloorPlan(x, y, imageViewWH)) {

                // Create a Pin on tapped location
                MyImageView newPinView = new MyImageView(getContext());
                newPinView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(imageViewWH, imageViewWH));
                newPinView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_location_on_black_48dp));
                newPinView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

                // Add to FrameLayout
                addView(newPinView);
                imgPointArray.add(newPinView);
                // Move to mouse center
                setAbsoluteLocationCentered(newPinView, x, y);
            }Log.d("PlayAreaView", "onSingleTapConfirmed,getChildCount"+getChildCount());
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override //双击
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("--onDoubleTap---");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("--onDoubleTapEvent---");
            return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTapOnFloorPlan(int tapX, int tapY, int imageViewWH) {
        Rect bounds = imgFloorPlan.getDrawable().getBounds();
        int x = (imgFloorPlan.getMeasuredWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (imgFloorPlan.getMeasuredHeight() - bounds.height()) / 2;

        int imageX1 = x + (imageViewWH / 2);
        int imageX2 = x + bounds.width();
        int imageY1 = y;
        int imageY2 = y + bounds.height();

        if (tapX >= imageX1 && tapX <= imageX2 && tapY >= imageY1 && tapY <= imageY2) {
            Log.d("ZoomLayout", "isTapOnFloorPlan: " + true);
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("ZoomLayout", "isTapOnFloorPlan: " + false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void setAbsoluteLocationCentered(View v, int x, int y) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
        int viewRadiusX = params.width / 2;
        int viewRadiusY = params.height;

        x = x - viewRadiusX;
        y = y - viewRadiusY;

        setAbsoluteLocation(v, x, y);
    }

    private void setAbsoluteLocation(View v, int x, int y) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams alp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        alp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
        v.setLayoutParams(alp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

The key point is matrix.

First time, scale the image into imageview and save the matrix you used to scale image(original Width Height).
Please don't use any auto scale method such as fitCenter attribute of a view.
scaleType must be matrix.

Old image + matrix = image in the view.

when onMesure and onScale
Image in the view + matrix (Public this matrix) = scaled image
other view + the public matrix = scale with image togeather

Also can use matrix to scale point to the same ratio.

Keywords to help your implementation:
ZoomLayout, GestureDetector, ScaleGestureDetector